# [MoveIt!] How to set a start pose with python?

Tags: ros, python, moveit, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

is it possible to set the pose (e.g. described as a list of joint angles) of the robot to certain values without planning a path, using the python move_group interface?
Possibly there doesn't exist a path from my current pose A to the desired start pose B, but I want to find a path from B to C.

I think the '[set_start_state](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_commander/html/classmoveit__commander_1_1move__group_1_1MoveGroupCommander.html#a20fb40fbc2425e5d308924d9f4bbac6f)' function is supposed to provide this; however, I don't know how the start point is supposed to be specified (as msg).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245487/%5Bmoveit!%5D-how-to-set-a-start-pose-with-python?/) by [F4bich](https://answers.ros.org/users/27705/f4bich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2016-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears to be a RobotState message from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/moveit-users/ZYsWL1jRWyY). You can print out the start_state to see what it consists of.

---

Originally posted by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) with karma: 592 on 2016-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [F4bich](https://answers.ros.org/users/27705/f4bich/) on 2016-10-12**:
Using the robot_state doesn't work for me.
I used these functions:

```
state = robot.get_current_state()
group.set_start_state(state)
```

If the state is set like that, and then a path is planned somewhere else, the path will start in the state it was before setting it to something else.